# Do i need to set constrains?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6

We have this product in which we started long time ago with the older `Xcode 5` .
In this project, there is a separate `storyboard` for iPhones, and iPads. When the program starts we chose the right storyboard according to the device .

With the new `Xcode6`,when we open the same project, we have the old storyboard for iPads, in which now the option `"auto layout"` and `"use size class"`, are **not** checked for it(iPads) .

What happens is that the app is running on all iPads,with this storyboard,which does not have constrains,or auto layout, and it works perfectly on all iPads screens.

For the iPhone storyboard,we do set auto layout and constrains,so there is not problem.

Question is, do we have to set `auto layout` and `constrains` to the iPad `storyboard` although it works great on all iPad sizes without it ?

In general, how is that it works on all screens *without* `auto layout`? is it because the **aspect ration** is the same for all iPads ? is it safe ?

I have read here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2041295 and he says that without auto layout the `autorisizingmask` will take control over the different sizes. so the question becomes more relevant - WHY DO I NEED AUTO-LAYOUT HEADACHE ?

Comment: The reason is that the iPad has only one resolution (in points), so it doesn't have to actually layout nothing. But with Xcode6 you can do it all with only one storyboard by using Size Classes.

Comment: No, for points I mean coordinate points, the one iOS uses for coordinates since iPhone4 came out. So every iPad has 768x1024 points of resolution, be it retina or not, while iPhones differ one from the other in that aspect. If you put the right constraints most things will be the same both in iPhone and iPad I think, then you can make things different by "Installing" different views or constraints depending on the Size Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need. If everything works and looks OK, leave it alone.

Auto-layout will be useful, when you add some dynamic behavior: resizing, content height changing, etc.

Finally auto-layout is not as painful as you think. Working with `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` dynamic height cells is much easier at the latest SDK.
After all, you do not have to set EVERY constraint. You are able to setup constraints for specific controllers and views only.